# Magento Enterprise Edition: Custom module not showing admin configuration

Tags: admin, magento-enterprise, configuration

I have developed a magento module. It works fine for community edition and enterprise edition in my local environment. After installed it in the live site it works fine for community edition, but not for enterprise edition. It is not showing any admin configuration in enterprise edition. Am I missing anything? Please guide me as soon as possible.

Comment: I know this sound 'cliche', but did you clear the cache, and re-logged in the admin panel?

Comment: Yes , I have cleared my cache,log,session,report and locks. But still I can't see any admin configuration.Thanks for your instant reply.

Comment: Does your module get listed in System->Configuration->Advanced? Anyway...maybe this helps: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store Happy debugging.

Comment: No , I also can't see my module at System->Configuration->Advanced. But my module's database tables has been created and in core_config_data table module's entry has also been stored.
Thanks again for that debugging link.

Comment: It's Your Module Boostrap file (Module_Name.xml) present in /src/app/etc/modules ?

Comment: You have both a CE and EE install in production? How does that work?

Comment: Yes , it is inside the "/app/etc/modules/" directory. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Currently I have only use EE production. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a copy of enterprise edition on hand, but it *should* load the "declared module" configuration in the same place as CE

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
protected function _getDeclaredModuleFiles()
{
    //...
}
```

It sounds like there's some customization to your production EE system that's preventing either this line

```
$moduleFiles = glob($etcDir . DS . 'modules' . DS . '*.xml');
```

or the subsequent sorting

```
    foreach ($moduleFiles as $v) {
        $name = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $v);
        $name = substr($name[count($name) - 1], 0, -4);

        if ($name == 'Mage_All') {
            $collectModuleFiles['base'][] = $v;
        } else if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'Mage_') {
            $collectModuleFiles['mage'][] = $v;
        } else {
            $collectModuleFiles['custom'][] = $v;
        }
    }
```

from finding your module.  I'd add some debugging code here too see why Magento can't see your module in production.

Answer (score 1):

We also had problems related to missing modules and my 2 cents solution is: after trying clearing all possible caches, reset file system permissions: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions

that solved the problem for us